# Run AnyCPU as 32-bit on 64-bit systems

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit

We are using a Third-Party assembly that seems to be compiled as AnyCPU.

However, we have a number of installations of our application where this leads to problems. This Third-Party assembly makes use of the oracle dataaccess library, and will not work on 64-bit machines where only a 32-bit oracle client is installed.

Installing a additional 64-bit oracle client would be possible, but also expensive (takes a lot of time, many machines have to be updated etc.)

Is there a way to force a AnyCPU .Net assembly to run as 32-bit without recompiling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [CorFlags.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Example (set 32BIT flag):

```
corflags [path]\[YourAssembly.exe] /32Bit+
```

Comment: +1. An example is http://www.lextm.com/2009/03/sharpdevelop-on-x64-windows-issue.html

Comment: All changing the flags on the 3rd party assembly will do is cause a runtime error if loaded into a 64 bit process (see doco https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(v=vs.110).aspx). OP already *has* a runtime error, so I can't see this helps much :-/.
He needs to change the flags on the EXE that starts the process, and whilst he could use corflags for this (ie in-the-field), long term it's massively simpler just to retarget to x86 at compile-time

Comment: @piers7 *"He needs to change the flags on the EXE that starts the process"*: Yes, that's what my answer says. *"and whilst he could use corflags for this (ie in-the-field)"*: Yes, that's what OP asked for.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you are building the .EXE that has a reference to a AnyCPU third party assembly you need to build your project as x86. This project can reference AnyCPU assemblies but being marked as x86 it will run as a 32 bit process on both 32 bit and 64 bit Windows.

Comment: This is a better answer for the OP's actual problem