# How to set/change target platform of installed visual basic app? Instructions regarding Location of corflag.exe & actual command execution

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I do not know much about programming, so forgive me for such basic question. I am trying to run one app which I use to practice mcqs. It runs fine in windows 7 32 bit system, but gives following error in windows 10 64 bit system.

"The type initializer for -- threw an exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID --  failed due to the following error: 80040154"

after google search I was told to change target platform to x64 or Any CPU. I have installed visual studio 2015. My question is how to proceed from here. Which file is a project file in installation folder , which I should open in visual studio to change target platform ? There are many .dll files and main .exe file to execute the app. Which is project file among these ? Or should I open installer file for the given app ?

Please someone give step by step instructions to change target platform. Main problem here is I am unable to find project file of "installed" program made by third party. Thanks !

Comment: This then has nothing to do with c++ or c# .. only visual basic. Please tag correctly

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly and all you have is the compiled code, you could use [CorFlags.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(v=vs.110).aspx) with the `/32BITREQ+` flag on the main .exe file to force it to run in 32-bit mode on the 64-bit PC.  If so, perhaps a dupe of questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945664/run-anycpu-as-32-bit-on-64-bit-systems)?

Comment: @mark Thank you. I do not have original source code of this VB.net application. I installed this app on my system using installation file given by third party. Is it possible to use this CorFlags.exe with main application .exe file found inside installation folder ? if so can you please tell me ,where can I find this CorFlags.exe file (I have visual studio 2015 Enterprise installed in 64 bit windows 10 system). Whether It will open command prompt and in which folder in command prompt I will have to execute this file ?

Comment: In my Visual Studio 2015 start menu folder there is Visual Studio Tools / Developer Command Prompt for VS2015.  Using that sets the path so that CorFlags.exe can be found - in my case it's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools.  Assuming you have permissions to update the installed .exe, you should be able to run CorFlags against it.

Comment: @Mark Wow. Thank you very much. you saved my life. I was searching since last week for such a direct explanation, and you finally did it for me. It worked and I am able to use this much needed application. Million thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough points to just add a comment yet, but it sounds like you don't have the original source code (not just the exe and dll files) for this app you are trying to run. If that is true, then I don't think there is anything you can do. You would need to ask the vendor to add support for 64-bit Windows 10. Perhaps the app is open source so you can download the code???

If you do have the source code used to create the app, you would open the project (that would be the .vbproj file if it is vb.net) in Visual Studio and then select Project on the menu bar, which drops down a menu list and select the last item which should be Properties. Once at that window, select Compile on the left side. From there you will see a Platform dropdown in the upper center and the Target CPU dropdown in the middle left. I'd adjust the latter first to Any CPU. If you select x64 then it won't run on your 32-bit Win 7. Then click the Start button just under the menu bar and see if it will build and run. If it does you're done. You can find the new exe it made in /bin/Debug

**EDIT:**

As stated by @Mark above in the question's comments, use CorFlags.exe with the /32BITREQ+ flag on the main .exe file to force it to run in 32-bit mode on the 64-bit PC

Comment: Thank you. So it is clear that if I do not have source code of this application I can not change it's target platform. Many solutions on various sites were suggesting to change target platform but no one mentioned that original source code is prerequisite for that. I was trying hard without this knowledge. Sometimes knowing something is not possible is all that we should know.

Comment: Correct. Setting target platform is done before compiling the application. If you must run this on Win 10 and can't get a new version from the vendor that works, you might look into installing a virtual machine running Win 7.

Comment: As suggested by @Mark such application can be run in x64 bit system by using corflags command in developer command prompt of visual studio, without even having original source code. May be it is because of my limited knowledge in this field, I required very direct and clear instructions. Thank you for your comments.